# MS Access text box changes background color when clicked

Tags: ms-access, formatting

In my MS Access continuous form, when I click on a hyperlinked text box the BackColor changes to white.

[image]

So even though the BackStyle is set to transparent, this happens. Any suggestions on how to eliminate this? Ideally it would be nice if the background color always stayed the same, even when clicked.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the alternate back colour of your detail section?

Comment: @Zaider I programatically change the color of the background as well. I've seen that trick before so maybe I need to programmatically change the alternate color as well?

Comment: It could be.  Try setting it to the color that you always want your background of the box to be such as white.